# How to simply achieve inclusive or in regex?

Tags: regex

Is there a way to represent inclusive or (that is to match `A`, `B` or `AB`)

(assuming `A`, `B` are regex sub-expressions)

that is simpler than this regex `((?:AB)|(?:A|B))` and this `((?:AB?)|(?:B))` ?

---

I mean, is there a kind of built in operator that performs the same action?

If not, why regex lack such a crucial operator? or is it just me who think that it's important?

Comment: "We had one problem, and we've decided to solve it with regex. Now we have two problems"...

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you mentioned `AB|A|B`?

```js
const regex = /AB|A|B/;
console.log(
  regex.test('AB'),
  regex.test('A'),
  regex.test('B')
);
```